# New Solution no longer allowing me to specify name, location and solution name

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to turn on the ability to enter a Name, Location and Solution name when creating a class library project in Visual Studio 2015? Currently when I click on New Project and select a C# Class Library it only asked for a name. Looking at a tutorial I noticed these 3 boxes were available when doing this in the video. If I click on the Universal Windows App template, these 3 fields are available but not in the Class Library.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem when I looked at a machine that had these 3 inputs available at project creation. The reason they no longer were available was because on my machine I apparently unchecked the "Save new projects when created" options in the Projects and Solutions area of the Options settings.